# Not understanding not null default

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

So I was under the impression that NOT NULL DEFAULT if used along with a column name would populate default values

```
INSERT INTO TPAVIT/SP001F ( sp1ruln,SP1FILE,SP1FLD,        
SP1CND,SP1VAL,SP1STID)                         
VALUES(3,'ITMRVA','ENGNO','LIKE','%416050%','PLD')
```

The below error is coming up:

```
Null values not allowed in column or variable SP1SEQNO.
```

but i had defined SP1SEQNO as below

```
SP1SEQNO   CHAR(3)      NOT NULL DEFAULT
```

So shouldn't this supply a default value if the INSERT doesn't? this field is a primary key though.

Comment: You don't specify what the default value is.

Comment: I thought it would be the default value based on the data type? See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/intro/src/tpc/db2z_defaultvalues.html

Comment: May be you should use the reference manual for the specific version of _your_ product, not DB2 for z/OS v11.

Comment: What is the DB2 version?

Answer (score 1):

I think the `primary key` is the problem here. It doesn't really make sense to have a default value for a primary key column since you can only add that default value to the table once. After that you would get duplicate key errors. To fix it, you need to remove `DEFAULT`, and specify a unique key in the `INSERT` statement.

Alternatives:

1. Make the field numeric, and define the column with `AS IDENTITY`.
2. Make the field numeric, and use a sequence to populate the field with `NEXT VALUE FOR sequence-name`. in your `INSERT` statement.

I prefer the sequence as it is easier to restart.